# How do I fix a lot of broken packages?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, 15.10

I'm currently running on Ubuntu 15.10, but I want to update to 16.04. But the updater says I have broken packages. But, in my opninion, I have way too much broken packages and I have no idea why they became broken...

When I use Synaptic Package Manager and I click Edit > Fix Broken Packages, but that does nothing, doesn't even show anything.

Here is the output of my broken packages:

```
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 > ( perl ) (< 5.22.1~)
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 5.22.1~)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 Breaks on libgnome-desktop-3-10 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.2-2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 Conflicts on libmwaw-0.3-3v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.3.5-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 Conflicts on libodfgen-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.4-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.16.3-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken php-cli:amd64 Depends on php7.0-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 7.0.4-7ubuntu2 | 7.0.5-2+deb.sury.org~wily+1 > ( php )
Broken unity-lens-music:amd64 Conflicts on unity-scope-musicstores [ amd64 ] < 6.9.0+15.04.20141219-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken php-json-schema:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken python3-click-package:amd64 Conflicts on python3-click [ amd64 ] < 0.4.39.1+15.10.20150702-0ubuntu2 -> 6.2-2ubuntu1 > ( universe/python )
Broken libmono-corlib2.0-cil:amd64 Depends on mono-runtime [ amd64 ] < 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 -> 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 > ( interpreters ) (< 3.2.9)
Broken jsonlint:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken libmono-i18n-west2.0-cil:amd64 Depends on libmono-corlib2.0-cil [ amd64 ] < 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 > ( cli-mono ) (>= 3.2.8)
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Broken libmetacity-private3a:amd64 Breaks on libmetacity-private3 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.17.2-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1:3.18)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken libmono-system2.0-cil:amd64 Depends on libmono-corlib2.0-cil [ amd64 ] < 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 > ( cli-mono ) (>= 3.2.8)
Broken libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 Conflicts on libcdr-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libmono-security2.0-cil:amd64 Depends on libmono-corlib2.0-cil [ amd64 ] < 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 > ( cli-mono ) (>= 3.2.8)
Broken libcheese7:amd64 Depends on cheese-common [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 -> 3.18.1-2ubuntu3 > ( gnome ) (= 3.16.1-1ubuntu2)
Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 -> 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10)
Broken libmono-posix2.0-cil:amd64 Depends on libmono-corlib2.0-cil [ amd64 ] < 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 > ( cli-mono ) (>= 3.2.8)
Broken libwpd-0.10-10v5:amd64 Depends on libwpd-0.10-10 [ amd64 ] < 0.10.0-2ubuntu4 -> 0.10.1-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.10.0-2ubuntu4)
Broken xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-21 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libperl5.20:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (= 5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2)
Broken libmono-corlib4.0-cil:amd64 Depends on mono-runtime [ amd64 ] < 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu4 -> 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4 > ( interpreters ) (< 3.2.9)
Broken libcheese-gtk23:amd64 Depends on libcheese7 [ amd64 ] < 3.16.1-1ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.4.0)
Broken libplank0:amd64 Depends on libplank-common [ amd64 ] < 0.10.1-1 -> 0.11.1-1 > ( universe/utils ) (= 0.10.1-1)
Broken libhunspell-1.3-0v5:amd64 Depends on libhunspell-1.3-0 [ amd64 ] < 1.3.3-3ubuntu3 -> 1.3.3-4ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 1.3.3-3ubuntu3)
Broken checkbox-ng-service:amd64 Depends on checkbox-ng [ amd64 ] < 0.20.1-1 -> 0.23-2 > ( utils ) (= 0.20.1-1)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java )
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 -> 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java )
Broken libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken python3.4:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Broken python3.4-minimal:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Broken tzdata-java:amd64 Depends on tzdata [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 -> 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04 > ( libs ) (= 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10)
Broken libpython3.4:amd64 Depends on libpython3.4-stdlib [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-9ubuntu1 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-9ubuntu1)
Broken openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 Depends on tzdata-java [ amd64 ] < 2016d-0ubuntu0.15.10 > ( java )
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken openjdk-7-jre:amd64 Depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless [ amd64 ] < 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.2 > ( java ) (= 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.2)
Broken openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 Depends on openjdk-7-jre [ amd64 ] < 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.2 > ( java ) (= 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.2)
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
Broken php-composer-spdx-licenses:amd64 Breaks on composer [ amd64 ] < 1.0.0~alpha10+20150602-1 -> 1.0.0~beta2-1 > ( universe/php ) (< 1.0.0~alpha11)
Broken composer:amd64 Depends on php-cli [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 > ( php )
```

How do I fix all this?
Thanks

Comment: try to `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: try running this command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @HoussemGuesmi use `apt`, as `apt-get` is being replaced with `apt` on 16.04.

Comment: @LittleByBlue ther is no source saying that apt-get is being replaced in fact both work still and will work still at least until EOL of 16.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually the reason for this issue is due to a failed/interrupted package update.

If caused by dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

If you get you recieved one of the following errors:

- Encountered a section with no Package: header
- Problem with MergeList…
- The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Remove and rebuilt the package lists:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

If you get the following error

- Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock – open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

The try the following

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo fuser -cuk /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

If due to ‘Unmet dependencies for installed packages’, fix in the ‘Synaptic Package Manager.’:

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager
2. Click ‘Status’ (left side)
3. Choose ‘Broken’
4. Remove the broken packages

Comment: You are my hero! No more broken packages, it's all fixed! Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help you @Mason ! :)

Comment: Mason, I have almost the exact same set of broken packages. Could you indicate what set of commands provided by @tekNorah fixed your issue?

Comment: @Alex the set of commands, provided by @tekNorah, that fixed my issue were `sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update` and `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

Everytime i ran "sudo apt-get update" i saw a bunch of IGN/ignores..so I manually modified the sources list (sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list) and updated the list names using I regenerated from https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php

or just copy these in:

Ubuntu Main Repos

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted universe multiverse
```